# json schema validation: a string field required if another array field contains specific value

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

cant build validation for simple case:
if sources field contains "OTHER" in values then "sourceOtherDescription" must be required.
Shall pass validation

```
{ 
   "sources": ["RENTS"]
}


{
       "sources": ["RENTS", "OTHER"],
       "sourceOtherDescription": "other income"
 }
```

This should not pass validation since sources contains "OTHER"

```
{
    "sources": ["RENTS", "OTHER"]
}
```

The schema that I was able to produce. Does not really work

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "money-sources",
  "title": "Money Sources",
  "description": "Money Sources definitions",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["sources"],
  "properties": {
    "sources": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "RENTS",
          "MEMBER_FEES",
          "PROFIT",
          "SALES_SECURITIES",
          "INTERNAL_GROUP_TRANSFERS",
          "OTHER"
        ]
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "sourceOtherDescription": { "type": "string", "minLength": 3}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,

  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "sources": {
          "type": "array",
            "contains": {"const": "OTHER"}
        }
      },
      "required": ["sourceOtherDescription"]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "sources": {
          "type": "array",
            "contains": {
              "enum": [ 
                "RENTS",
                "MEMBER_FEES",
                "PROFIT",
                "SALES_SECURITIES"
              ]
            }
        }
      }
    }
    , false
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `if-then` it works for me this way:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "money-sources",
  "title": "Money Sources",
  "description": "Money Sources definitions",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "sources" ],
  "properties": {
    "sources": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "RENTS",
          "MEMBER_FEES",
          "PROFIT",
          "SALES_SECURITIES",
          "INTERNAL_GROUP_TRANSFERS",
          "OTHER"
        ]
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "sourceOtherDescription": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "sources": {
        "type": "array",
        "contains": {
          "const": "OTHER"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [ "sourceOtherDescription" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: oh, is that simple? thank you very much @Clemens. it works like a charm.